# How to constrain Graphics scale?

Tags: graphics, constraint

As you can see, the scale of X and Y "adapts" to the scale of the circle. How can I stop the scale from increasing so as to create a "circle-spreading" effect?

[image]

Code:

```
g = Table[Graphics[Table[Circle[{0, 0}, r], {r, 0, t, 0.05}], 
    ImagePadding -> 10, Frame -> True], {t, 0, 2, 0.02}];
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]
Export["whorl.gif", g]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to fix the plot range?

```
Animate[Graphics[Table[Circle[{0, 0}, r], {r, 0, t, 0.05}], 
  ImagePadding -> 20, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, 2, 0.02}]
```

[image]